# Proving $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+|y|}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I'm unable to prove that

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^2+|y|}=0$$

I tried with polar coordinates but I'm unable to reach a function that depends only on $\rho$

$$0\le\frac{\rho^3\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)+|\rho\sin(\theta)|}=\frac{\rho^2\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|}\leq \dots ?$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the fact that $x^2 \leq x^2 + |y|$ and then apply the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. After reading your work, you may show that
$$\frac{x^2y}{x^2+|y|}=\frac{\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)|\sin(\theta)|}{\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|}
\leq \rho^2$$
that is
$$\rho^2\cos^2(\theta)|\sin(\theta)|\leq \rho^3\cos^2(\theta)+\rho^2|\sin(\theta)|.$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: since $0\le|\sin(\theta)|,|\cos(\theta)|\le 1$ you have that
$$0\le\left|\frac{\rho^2\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{\rho\cos^2(\theta)+|\sin(\theta)|}\right|
\le \frac{\rho^2}{\rho[1-\sin^2(\theta)]+|\sin(\theta)|}\le
\begin{cases}
\rho^2 & 1<\rho\\
\\
\rho & 0< \rho\le 1 
\end{cases}$$
since $0\le 1-\sin^2(\theta)\le 1$ and $|\sin(\theta)|\le 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that $$x^2+|y|\geq 2|x||y|^{1/2}$$ so
$$\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+|y|}\le \frac{|x|^2|y|}{2|x||y|^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{2}|x||y|^{1/2}$$ and this tends to zero for $x,y$ tends to zero.

Answer (score 2):

$|\frac {x^{2}y} {x^{2}+|y|}| \leq x^{2}$  because $x^{2}+|y| \geq |y|$.